# kitchen light turning on and off

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have a ceiling light (boob light) in my kitchen that started going on and off. When turned on the two light bulbs in the light fixture go on then a while later one of them goes off. If left on it eventually comes back on on its own. The House is 7 years old and we never had that issue before. I've changed the light bulb but the problem persist. I have put lower wattage (CFL) bulbs instead in case there were overheating, then again to no avail. I changed the light fixture and there again same result.There is no flickering.

Since the problem persists with new bulb and new fixture, what is the next thing that I can fix?

Anyone had that before and found the source of the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lower wattage CFL likely won't reduce heat.  Heat from a CFL is not from the generation of light, it's from the internal ballast.  I'd try switching to even more economical LED bulbs that don't generally generate as much heat as the ballast in a CFL.  If a "boob light" is a round surface mount fixture I'd change the whole fixture.  The "orange" big box store has that in two sizes for under $30 and $40 respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tyson. I will try with LED bulbs. For the light fixture, I thought it was the culprit too so I changed it but the problem persists.

Comment: I meant specifically change to LED fixture with built-in LEDs, not replaceable LED bulbs.

Comment: Oh,OK I'll look into LED fixture. Thanks again.